# Scala return type is not automatically inferred in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I reinstalled IntelliJ/Scala on my computer and I am now seeing a strange issue with IntelliJ's type inference.

See the first image for the error and the second image for a workaround.

[image: issue]
[image: Temp fix]

The issue is that the return type of ev.pure(()) which is unit is not inferred. ev is of type cats.effect.Effect[F]. If I run sbt run from the command line this works fine and compiles without the added [Unit].

> Java version: 11.0.2
>
> Scala version: 2.12.8
>
> IntelliJ version:
> IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
> Build #IU-191.6707.61, built on April 16, 2019
>
> Scala Plugin Version: 2019.1.7

I've tried re-importing the project and ensuring all scala/sbt/intellij are all the latest versions.

Comment: From time to time IntelliJ may highlight Scala code incorrectly. What do you expect posting this at SO?

Comment: This issue has been consistent for me ever since i reinstalled and wasn't an issue before that. I am thinking that I messed something up or maybe someone knows something I don't that may resolve this issue. I understand that intellij isn't perfect at resolving types. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that during "re-installation" you actually installed different version?

Comment: yes that is for sure possible. I installed the latest versions and don't recall what versions of everything I had before

Comment: Well, different versions can highlight differently. I guess you found proper place to report about issue in Scala plugin https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15384

Comment: But I guess actual code would be better than screenshots.

Comment: Yep! Thought I would attack this issue from multiple fronts though and see if I was just missing something obvious

Comment: And I can add code- Just wanted to capture the error

Comment: Versions of Intellij and Scala plugin would be also helpful there.

Comment: Sorry but nobody will be able to reproduce your issue from your code snippet. It will just not compile for anybody except you. It's not so easy to write useful issue report.

Comment: Tried these options and still get the error

Comment: You may have a better/more useful response opening an issue at intellij ... This is just a Q&A site ...